# Why ETCD exist two same key?

Tags: etcd

I use `etcd` store config for Golang my app, running for a while, I find two same keys in the `etcd` and it's curious for me, the `key` in `etcd` is not unique ?

I use `etcdctl get --prefix /` get the keys.

Answer (score 0):

By using `--prefix` option, you asks etcd for all keys that **starts with** some text (`/` in your case). Consider this example:

```sh
$ etcdctl put foo bar
OK
$ etcdctl put foofoo barbar
OK
$ etcdctl put baz baz
OK
$ etcdctl get foo
foo
bar
$ etcdctl get --prefix foo
foo
bar
foofoo
barbar
```

When you skip `--prefix` part, you are getting only value for given key (`bar` for key `foo`), however when you add `--prefix` you will get values for all keys starting with **foo**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the duplicate key contain some special characters...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).